# vanilla js onclick if statement issue

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm attempting to affect a change to an elements height when another element is clicked. I'm using an if else statement in order to toggle the change back and forth.

```
var bnr = document.getElementById("bnr");
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

if (bnr.style.height = "250px") { 
  btn.onclick = function() {
    bnr.style.height = "600px";
  };
}   
else if (bnr.style.height = "600px") { 
  btn.onclick = function() {;
    bnr.style.height = "250px";
  };
};
```

The first statement works, changing the elements height to 600px however the second statement isn't working and the element stays at 600px if you click again.

Is anyone able to see where I am going wrong here?

[JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/crfdhtes/)

Comment: The if statements should be '==' not '='

Comment: That seems to have stopped it working completely https://jsfiddle.net/66un8s8a/

Comment: You should try stepping through your code with a debugger, and you would find the issues quite quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs on page load (I assume) and as the height is 250 px at that point, creates a click event to set the height to 600 px.  Every time you click the button, the same event will run, as the code in your question will not run again.  I think you want:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {

  var bnr = document.getElementById("bnr");

  if (bnr.style.height === "250px")
  { 
      bnr.style.height = "600px";
  } else {
      bnr.style.height = "250px";
  }
};
```

Comment: This seems un-DRY with the repetition of "250px". I also think it should have at least been suggested to avoid the anti-pattern of setting, checking, and resetting styles directly on the element.

Comment: @torazaburo - it answers the question in hand, explaining the why of where they were (fundamentally) going wrong.  Your answer would have clouded this somewhat - if you disagree, please feel free to provide your own answer.

Comment: It was already provided by @pavgra. There is always a question about how much to "open the box", in terms of answering with some minimal fixes to solve the "question in hand", vs. stepping back and pointing out better approaches, either in terms of simplifying the problem, or making it less likely that the PO would have encountered the problem in the first place, or just indicating best practices. Personally, I lean toward the latter: I feel, let's take advantage of teaching moments! However, although some posters or readers might like this, some might hate it.

Answer (score 0):

You shold do like this:

```
var bnr = document.getElementById("bnr");
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
  if (bnr.style.height == "250px" || !bnr.style.height)
  { 
      bnr.style.height = "600px";
  }     
  else if(bnr.style.height == "600px")
  { 
      bnr.style.height = "250px";
  };      
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/crfdhtes/1/

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use classes manipulation to change element's style. So you can add "expanded" class:

```css
#bnr.expanded {
  height: 600px;
}
```

and toggle it on click:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
  var bnr = document.getElementById('bnr');
  bnr.classList.toggle('expanded');
};
```

Comment: This will not work in IE < 10, in case that is an issue.